# Automatically creation of test databases using Maven

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jetty, jax-rs

I just integrated PostgreSQL into my first JAX-RS project and now I am wondering how I can setup databases to test my application using Maven. I already managed to create the database and the tables I need before the test phase starts, but I was not able to fill the tables with test data. I am missing a good guide that tells me how to setup my `spozz_db_testdata.xml` file. I currently just know how I could add rows that only use primitive types like string or integer, but what about binary data?

Any solution or tips will help.

**Current spozz_db_testdata.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
    <avatars />  
    <users />  
    <spots />  
    <spot_revisions />  
    <spot_images />  
    <comments />  
</dataset>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.avedo.spozz</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spozz-Webservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jetty.version>9.1.0.v20131115</jetty.version>
        <jersey.version>1.8</jersey.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <apache.commons.version>1.3.2</apache.commons.version>
        <apache.http.version>4.3.2</apache.http.version>
        <jsp.version>2.5</jsp.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <sql.maven.plugin.version>1.5</sql.maven.plugin.version>
        <postgresql.jdbc.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresql.jdbc.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

                ...


        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

                    ...

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sql.maven.plugin.version}</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:spozz_db</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have 
                        maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    <!-- All executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-schema-before-test-if-any</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Need another database to drop the targeted one -->
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:postgres</url>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>DROP SCHEMA spozz CASCADE</sqlCommand>
                            <!-- Ignore error when database is not available -->
                            <onError>continue</onError>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>create-schema</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <srcFiles>
                                <srcFile>src/main/sql/spozz-schema.sql</srcFile>
                            </srcFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:spozz_db</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have maven 
                        to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    <!-- All executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>operation</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- Specific configurations -->
                        <configuration>
                            <type>CLEAN_INSERT</type>
                            <src>src/test/resources/spozz_db_testdata.xml</src>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>

                    ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/index.html. This does assume you have an empty shell database to target already created.  You would have to do a special setup step to create the empty shell database outside of Liquibase. However with that in place you can easily create database tables and populate tables with Liquibase and Maven.

Comment: Thanks, but the changelog based deploy mechanism of Liquibase is not suited for unit tests. However, DbUnit6 was designed for this purpose, I just don't know how to insert data. And I don't know how to handle BLOB (binary) data.